# How to get default address in transactional email magento 1.9.2.1

Tags: email, magento, transactional

How can I print the default address information of my newly registered customer in a transactional email?

I can't find any valid Information on the web.

What I have so far:

```
Neue Kundenregistrierung bei {{var store.getName()}}.<br />
E-Mail: {{var customer.getEmail()}}<br />
Vorname: {{var customer.getFirstname()}}<br />
Nachname: {{var customer.getLastname()}}<br />
Strasse: {{var customer.getAddresses().getStreetFull()}}<br />
Stadt: {{var customer.getAddresses().getCity()}}<br />
PLZ: {{var customer.getAddresses().getPostcode()}}<br />
Telefon: {{var customer.getAddresses().getTelephone()}}<br />
Firma: {{var customer.getAddresses().getCompany()}}<br />
ID: {{var customer.ID}}
```

but getAddresses() returns an array

Comment: Can you call `{{var customer.getPrimaryBillingAddress().getCity()}}` or `{{var customer.getPrimaryShippingAddress().getCity()}}`

Answer (score 0):

Found the correct solution. The Thing with Transactional Emails is, that you need to pass the data needed within the mail, before the mail is sent through magento.

I identified the code pieces for sending my customer notification email and passed an array of the customers address in an additional array.

like that:

```
    $addressData = $session->getCustomerAddress(); //get customers address from      session variable

                $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel("core/email_template")
                    ->loadDefault("customer_notification");

                $emailTemplateVariables = array();
                $emailTemplateVariables["customer"] = $customer;
                $emailTemplateVariables["plz"] = $addressData['postcode'];
                $emailTemplateVariables["city"] = $addressData['city'];
                $emailTemplateVariables["company"] = $addressData['company'];
                $emailTemplateVariables["street"] = $addressData['street'][0];
                $emailTemplateVariables["phone"] = $addressData['telephone'];

                $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);

                $mail = Mage::getModel("core/email")
//                ->setToName("Konstantin")
                ->setToEmail("mailtosendto@provider.com")
                ->setBody($processedTemplate)
                ->setFromEmail("senderemail@provider.com")
                ->setFromName("senders name")
                ->setSubject("**subject appering in mail header**")
                ->setType("html");
                try{
                    $mail->send();
                }
                catch(Exception $error)
                {
                    Mage::getSingleton("core/session")->addError($error->getMessage());
                    return false;
                }
```